# probability of winning a special sing-elimination tournament using dynamic programming and bitmask

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, dynamic-programming

Let's say we have `N` teams in a tournament and based on historical data we know what is the probability of each team winning any other team .Lets put all the probabilities in a matrix called `P` . `P[a][b]` is the probability team `a` winning team `b`. It is obvious that `P[a][a] = 0` and `P[a][b] = 1-P[b][a]`.

In this tournament at every round, two of teams compete against each other and the loser is eliminated. This two team are chosen randomly (with equal possibility of each team being picked). So at the first round we have `n` teams, next `n-1` teams and so on until only one team remains and becomes the champion. What is the probability of each team becoming the champion? ( `1 <= N <= 18`).

At first when I didn't know how to approach the problem but after some reading and search and keeping in mind that max `n` is `18` I figured at that using Dynamic programming and Bitmask is the way to go. How ever I couldn't figure at a solution. Here are my problems:

1. I have really hard time to figure at what are the sub problems and what sub problems should not be recomputed, basically I can't find a well defined recursive ( or not recursive) equation for the problem
2. In bitmask+dp problems we usually define something like `dp[mask][n] or dp[n][mask]`. I tried different approaches to define the mask but since the general solution is not clear to me there was no success

Some guidance on this two problems would be very helpful.

Comment: This looks somewhat similar to the famous **matrix chain multiplication** problem, which can be solved relatively easily with dynamic programming. But in matrix chain multiplication, the matrix are ordered and the only choice we have is how to parenthesize them. Whereas your problem requires to choose the order of the elements as well...

Comment: @Stef sorry but I cant see why are these problems similar. can you explain?

Comment: Imagine you want to calculate the product of matrices AxBxCxD. You can calculate (((AxB)xC)xD) or ((AxB)x(CxD)) or (Ax(Bx(CxD))) or some other way. The problem of matrix chain multiplication asks to find the "best" parenthesizing way. Note that this looks a little like organizing a tournament between the matrices. Each multiplication of two matrices is like one game being played between these two matrices.

Comment: However you are not allowed to change the order of matrices, so for instance you can't choose (AxD)x(BxC). So that makes the problem of matrix chain multiplication slightly easier than your problem, because there are fewer tournaments allowed.

Comment: @Stef Thanks I understood what you are saying and read the matrix problem but still can't clearly define the sub-problems of my own problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a dynamic programming problem.

If you have a vector **V** that gives the probability of each player being in the game after **n** rounds, then you can calculate the player probabilities for **n+1** rounds by:

**V'<sub>i</sub> = 2/((18-n)(17-n)) * sum over all j!=i of [V<sub>i</sub>V<sub>j</sub>P<sub>i,j</sub>]**

That first factor is the probability that any given available match will be chosen, which depends on the number of previous rounds, because each successive round has fewer players to match up.

The second part is the probability of the players being available for each match, times the probability that the current player will win.

Just do this calculation 17 times to get the player probabilities after 17 rounds, which is the answer you're looking for.  You can even drop that first factor, and fix it at the end by normalizing the vector so that the probabilities sum to 1.